# oracle 11g select distinct issue

Tags: oracle, index

I have a big table (61mil rows) that has an indexed not-null column `ID`. I want to select the distinct values of that column. I expected the

```
select distinct id from bigtable ;
```

to run fast, making use of that index. Yet it takes more than 40sec to run on a fast server.

The EXPLAIN PLAN shows that a FAST FULL SCAN of that index takes place, whereas I'd expect a INDEX RANGE SCAN  instead. The cost comes up as 93000.

Please advise. Do I perhaps need a different index type?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the column name are completely useless

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete execution plan as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please

Comment: An index range scan is used for conditions like `id > 42`. Your query has to look at **all** id values to evaluate the distinct ones. Reading the complete index using a FAST FULL SCAN seems the only sensible approach to me.

Comment: If a fast full scan is all I can hope for, then I'd welcome suggestions on how to maintain that list of distinct values in other ways. I only run Standard Edition so MVs are not available.

Comment: Materialized views are available in the standard edition.  You don't get query rewrite so you'd need to alter your query to hit the MV rather than the table.  Is that an option?  From a data model standpoint, it sounds like you're missing a table with all the `id` values that `bigtable` can then have a foreign key reference to.  Then you'd just need to query that new dimension table.

Comment: And how many of those 61M IDs are distinct?

Comment: The secret sauce of making queries on largish table complete faster is very simple: use parallelism. Did you try that ? Use a /*+ PARALLEL n */ hint, where n is the number of cores you can afford to give to this query.

Comment: Oh and also; the query completes in 40 seconds. You say this is too long, and you say you want the results “fast”. Define fast. What would you consider acceptable? 10sec ? 5 sec? 1sec ? Less ?  And how is this query used in a business process ? How often do you run it ? How often does the table change in terms of ids ?

Comment: Thanks to all who have answered. I'll look again into MV licensing. The distinct IDs are about 50-100 as I wrote. Using PARALLEL 8 as a hint gave no benefit. 5sec would be acceptable. The query is used in the UI of the app so it must be sorta-real-time. Yes, that modelling change would be great but it's too late now.